# How to find mongo data through express route and print the data into jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

How to find mongo `data(db.collection_name.find())` through express route and print the data into jade template.

Here is my express route( I am using express2.5.8)

```
    app.get('/showData',function(req,res){
  db.collection('comments',function(err, data){
    if(err){
      throw err;
    }
    else{
      data.find();
      res.render('help', {data: data});
    }
  });
});
```

It through an error that `db.collection` is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick start, you can connect to the db first, and then store `db` in a variable:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var database;

// Connection URL 
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server 
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (!err) {
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");
  database = db;
  } 
})

app.get('/showData',function(req,res){
  database.collection('comments',function(err, data){
  if(err){
    throw err;
  }
  else {
    data.find();
    res.render('help', {data: data});
  }
});
```

Later you can move all the db connectivity functionality into separate file and just require it when needed.

Comment: Thanks, but i did the connectivity already haven't share the code of that sorry for that. I just want to know how to retrieve data from db, pass it through route and print it on jade template. I have found a very good tutorial which help me in that

http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/write-a-todo-list-with-express-and-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer myself below is the code:

Controller :

```
company.find({}, function(err, companies) {
  if (err){
    callback(err);
  }
  else{
    callback(null, companies);
  }
});
```

Route :

```
  app.get('/companies', isLoggedIn,function(req, res) {
    companyCtrl.companyList(function(err, companies){
      res.render('companies',{companies:companies});
    });
  });
```

Jade Template :

```
each val in companies
   tr                               
      td(data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" ) ID
      td(data-field="id" data-sortable="true")= val.id
      td(data-field="name" data-sortable="true")= val.name
```

In the above example i have used .find method in controller to fetch the documents in the collection and send them back to the route with callback function and jade display the results in the frontend